# How to convert old version typescript codes to latest

Tags: php, typescript

Old version of typescripts have quite a few difference, such as the usage of 'bool' instead of 'boolean'.

I try to get the php-typescript compiler work in Visual Studio 2015, however, it shows up over 2000 errors mainly because of the old version of code.

Is there a way to convert old version typescript code to the latest?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There is no automated way of doing it.

However since TypeScript 1.8 there is no need to do so. It added the **allowJs** flag that allows Javascript code to pass unharmed trough the compiler.

You can configure it like this in **tsconfig.json**:

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "system",
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "sourceMap": false,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "outDir": "dist"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Comment: thanks! But that makes it really painful to upgrade a very large project.

Comment: @JackYumCha that is true but might not be needed, I updated my answer, maybe that helps. :)